# In Python, how to mock a c extension class?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, typeerror

I'm trying to mock a class function which uses a c extension class inside it as follows, but I get `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'y.cExtensionClass'`.
code.py is a legacy code, and I really rather not to change it. Any suggestion?

code.py:

```
from x.y import cExtensionClass

class CodeClass():

    @staticmethod
    def code_function():
         cExtensionClass().cExtensionFunc()
```

test.py:

```
import code
from x.y import cExtensionClass

class test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_code_function(self)
        with patch.object(cExtensionClass, 'cExtensionFunc') as cExtensionFuncMock:   
            cExtensionFuncMock.return_value = None
            code.CodeClass.code_function()
            cExtensionFuncMock.assert_called_with()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patch `code.cExtensionClass` (not `x.y.cExtensionClass`).
Do `import code` instead of `from code cExtensionClass`.

```
import unittest

from mock import patch, Mock

import code

class test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_code_function(self):
        with patch('code.cExtensionClass') as m:
            m.return_value.cExtensionFunc = func = Mock()
            code.CodeClass.code_function()
            func.assert_called_with()

    #@patch('code.cExtensionClass')
    #def test_code_function(self, m):
    #    m.return_value.cExtensionFunc = func = Mock()
    #    code.CodeClass.code_function()
    #    func.assert_called_with()
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 196, in test_code_function
    with patch(code.cExtensionClass) as m:
  File "./../../test/mock/mock.py", line 1551, in patch
    getter, attribute = _get_target(target)
  File "./../../test/mock/mock.py", line 1389, in _get_target
    target, attribute = target.rsplit('.', 1)
AttributeError: type object 'y.cExtensionClass' has no attribute 'rsplit'

Comment: Found the problem, should have used string instead of the class.

Comment: Did you use `code.cExtensionClass` instead of `'code.cExtensionClass'`?

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. Works perfectly now. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user1819676, Try commented out decorator version, too. :)

Comment: Yeah, the decorator version is even cleaner :)

Comment: Why set `m.return_value.cExtensionFunc` to the mock, and not just `m.cExtensionFunc`? The latter works in my code, the former does not.

Comment: @MikeC, because `m` is a callable (class/function).

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [forbidden fruit](http://clarete.github.io/forbiddenfruit/)

## Forbidden Fruit

[image]

> This project aims to help you reach heaven while writing tests, but it
>   may lead you to hell if used on production code.
>
> It basically allows you to patch built-in objects, declared in C
>   through python. Just like this:

```
>>> from forbiddenfruit import curse
>>> def words_of_wisdom(self):
...     return self * "blah "
>>> curse(int, "words_of_wisdom", words_of_wisdom)
>>> assert (2).words_of_wisdom() == "blah blah "
```

> Boom! That's it, your int class now has the words_of_wisdom method. Do
>   you want to add a classmethod to a built-in class? No problem, just do
>   this:

```
>>> from forbiddenfruit import curse
>>> def hello(self):
...     return "blah"
>>> curse(str, "hello", classmethod(hello))
>>> assert str.hello() == "blah"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the entire cExtensionClass object, rather than just a single method of it.